# Robocopy "invalid parameter" for file names beginning with "-" (minus sign)

Tags: robocopy

I use robocopy to backup folders and individual files via a batch file. This works fine for all folders and nearly all files, but not for files where the name starts with a "-" (minus sign).

My OS: German Windows 7, 64 Bit. (I don't know if that matters.)

**My test batch file does this:**

```
SET fileName=-Test.rar
robocopy "folder 1" "folder 2" "%fileName%"
ECHO Errorlevel: %Errorlevel%
```

Where `%fileName%` is quoted because the file name may contain spaces as well.

**The result is an ERROR : Invalid Parameter**.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robustes Dateikopieren für Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Gestartet: Wed Nov 21 15:42:47 2018

   Quelle - E:\BackupThisFile\folder 1\
     Ziel - E:\BackupThisFile\folder 2\

    Dateien :
  Optionen: /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

FEHLER: Ungültiger Parameter #3 : "-Test.rar"
[...]
Errorlevel: 16
```

**Tested versions of "robocopy.exe":**

- XP010 (Windows XP?)
- XP026 (Windows 2000?)
- XP027 Win7 32 Bit
- XP027 Win7 64 Bit

It always resulted in the same error message or only the equivalent error code 16.

**Tested variation of the command:**

Then i have tried different variations of the command. Only 1 change (additional quotes) looked remotely promising:

```
robocopy "folder 1" "folder 2" \""%fileName%""
```

**But it didn't work either:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robustes Dateikopieren für Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Gestartet: Wed Nov 21 15:43:00 2018

   Quelle : E:\BackupThisFile\folder 1\
     Ziel : E:\BackupThisFile\folder 2\

    Dateien : "-Test.rar"

  Optionen: /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           0    E:\BackupThisFile\folder 1\

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

           Insgesamt   KopiertÜbersprungenKeine Übereinstimmung    FEHLER    Extras
Verzeich.:         1         0         1         0         0         0
  Dateien:         0         0         0         0         0         0
    Bytes:         0         0         0         0         0         0
   Zeiten:   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
```

Nothing was copied even though the file name parameter was kind of recognized.

I guess that the quotes in the value of the parameter are wrong as well.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: FYI, I've been able to recreate the problem and have also tried a number of ways around it and have failed.  The last test didn't work because you were trying to copy "-Test.rar" and not -Test.rar .

Comment: Thank You for testing it. I have seen that `"-Test.rar"` is not equal to `-Test.rar` but i hoped that repeated quotes (i tried 3 and 4 as well) would cancel each other out in some way.

Comment: FYI: My workaround is to replace the "-" with an "?". This copies at least all files where the name begins with exactly 1 leading char.